# C# - How to find all handles associated with current Process

Tags: c#, process

I want to find which files is currently opened by Excel, Word of PDF process.
In x64dbg i can see info about process and can see needed file, but C# and WMI looks like do not allow to get such information.

The handle.exe is not very good solution, I do not want to use it and parse data.

So is there any way to do it using C# and WMI, if not, then what Win32 API I can use to find Handles associated with process.
The ntdll.dll ->NtQueryInformationProcess it is allows me to get address of process but how to use it to read Handles?

Comment: [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.5.2)

Comment: I need I process Handles, i do not have a problem to find process, but i stuck with finding Opened Handles :(

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all, I have found a solution.[NtQueryObject hang when FileTypePipe](http://0memory.blogspot.it/2008/08/getfinalpathnamebyhandle-api-hungs.html)

So there is a lot of solutions in the internet but most of them have problem with hanging when getting name for FileTypePipe :)

```html
 public class ProcessUtility
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/ntoskrnl/api/ex/sysinfo/handle_table_entry.htm?ts=0,242
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        private struct SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION
        { // Information Class 16
            public ushort ProcessID;
            public ushort CreatorBackTrackIndex;
            public byte ObjectType;
            public byte HandleAttribute;
            public ushort Handle;
            public IntPtr Object_Pointer;
            public IntPtr AccessMask;
        }

        private enum OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS : int
        {
            ObjectBasicInformation = 0,
            ObjectNameInformation = 1,
            ObjectTypeInformation = 2,
            ObjectAllTypesInformation = 3,
            ObjectHandleInformation = 4
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        private struct OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION
        { // Information Class 1
            public UNICODE_STRING Name;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct UNICODE_STRING
        {
            public ushort Length;
            public ushort MaximumLength;
            public IntPtr Buffer;
        }

        [Flags]
        private enum PROCESS_ACCESS_FLAGS : uint
        {
            All = 0x001F0FFF,
            Terminate = 0x00000001,
            CreateThread = 0x00000002,
            VMOperation = 0x00000008,
            VMRead = 0x00000010,
            VMWrite = 0x00000020,
            DupHandle = 0x00000040,
            SetInformation = 0x00000200,
            QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
            Synchronize = 0x00100000
        }

        private enum FileType : uint
        {
            FileTypeChar = 0x0002,
            FileTypeDisk = 0x0001,
            FileTypePipe = 0x0003,
            FileTypeRemote = 0x8000,
            FileTypeUnknown = 0x0000,
        }

        [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
        private static extern uint NtQuerySystemInformation(int SystemInformationClass, IntPtr SystemInformation, int SystemInformationLength, ref int returnLength);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(PROCESS_ACCESS_FLAGS dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool DuplicateHandle(IntPtr hSourceProcessHandle, IntPtr hSourceHandle, IntPtr hTargetProcessHandle, out IntPtr lpTargetHandle, uint dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, uint dwOptions);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

        [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
        private static extern int NtQueryObject(IntPtr ObjectHandle, int ObjectInformationClass, IntPtr ObjectInformation, int ObjectInformationLength, ref int returnLength);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern uint QueryDosDevice(string lpDeviceName, StringBuilder lpTargetPath, int ucchMax);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool GetHandleInformation(IntPtr hObject, out uint lpdwFlags);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern FileType GetFileType(IntPtr hFile);

        private const int MAX_PATH = 260;
        private const uint STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH = 0xC0000004;
        private const int DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS = 0x2;
        private const uint FILE_SEQUENTIAL_ONLY = 0x00000004;
        private const int CNST_SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION = 0x10;
        private const int OBJECT_TYPE_FILE = 0x24;

        public static List<string> FindFilesByExtension(List<Process> target_processes, List<string> target_extensions)
        {
            List<string> aFilePaths = new List<string>();
            if (target_extensions == null || target_extensions.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Exceptions not defined");
            }
            foreach (Process process in target_processes)
            {
                List<string> aProcessFiles = GetPrcessFiles(target_processes);
                foreach (string file_path in aProcessFiles)
                {
                    if (target_extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file_path.ToLower()))
                        && !Path.GetFileName(file_path).StartsWith("~"))
                    {
                        aFilePaths.Add(file_path);
                    }
                }
            }
            return aFilePaths;
        }

        public static List<string> GetPrcessFiles(List<Process> target_processes)
        {
            List<string> aFiles = new List<string>();
            foreach (Process process in target_processes)
            {
                List<SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION> aHandles = GetFileHandles(process).ToList();
                foreach (SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION handle_info in aHandles)
                {
                    string file_path = GetFilePath(handle_info, process);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file_path))
                    {
                        aFiles.Add(file_path);
                    }
                }
            }
            return aFiles;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION> GetFileHandles(Process process)
        {
            List<SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION> aHandles = new List<SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION>();
            int handle_info_size = Marshal.SizeOf(new SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION()) * 20000;
            IntPtr ptrHandleData = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                ptrHandleData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(handle_info_size);
                int nLength = 0;

                while (NtQuerySystemInformation(CNST_SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION, ptrHandleData, handle_info_size, ref nLength) == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
                {
                    handle_info_size = nLength;
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptrHandleData);
                    ptrHandleData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
                }

                long handle_count = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(ptrHandleData).ToInt64();
                IntPtr ptrHandleItem = ptrHandleData + Marshal.SizeOf(ptrHandleData);

                for (long lIndex = 0; lIndex < handle_count; lIndex++)
                {
                    SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION oSystemHandleInfo = Marshal.PtrToStructure<SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION>(ptrHandleItem);
                    ptrHandleItem += Marshal.SizeOf(new SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION());
                    if (oSystemHandleInfo.ProcessID != process.Id || oSystemHandleInfo.ObjectType != OBJECT_TYPE_FILE)
                    { continue; }

                    aHandles.Add(oSystemHandleInfo);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptrHandleData);
            }
            return aHandles;
        }

        private static string GetFilePath(SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION systemHandleInformation, Process process)
        {
            IntPtr ipHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr openProcessHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr hObjectName = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                PROCESS_ACCESS_FLAGS flags = PROCESS_ACCESS_FLAGS.DupHandle | PROCESS_ACCESS_FLAGS.VMRead;
                openProcessHandle = OpenProcess(flags, false, process.Id);
                if (!DuplicateHandle(openProcessHandle, new IntPtr(systemHandleInformation.Handle), GetCurrentProcess(), out ipHandle, 0, false, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS))
                {
                    return null;
                }

                if (GetFileType(ipHandle) != FileType.FileTypeDisk)
                { return null; }

                int nLength = 0;
                hObjectName = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(256 * 1024);

                while ((uint)(NtQueryObject(ipHandle, (int)OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS.ObjectNameInformation, hObjectName, nLength, ref nLength)) == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(hObjectName);
                    if (nLength == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Length returned at zero!");
                        return null;
                    }
                    hObjectName = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
                }
                OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION objObjectName = Marshal.PtrToStructure<OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION>(hObjectName);

                if (objObjectName.Name.Buffer != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    string strObjectName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(objObjectName.Name.Buffer);
                    return GetRegularFileNameFromDevice(strObjectName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(hObjectName);

                CloseHandle(ipHandle);
                CloseHandle(openProcessHandle);
            }
            return null;
        }

        private static string GetRegularFileNameFromDevice(string strRawName)
        {
            string strFileName = strRawName;
            foreach (string strDrivePath in Environment.GetLogicalDrives())
            {
                var sbTargetPath = new StringBuilder(MAX_PATH);
                if (QueryDosDevice(strDrivePath.Substring(0, 2), sbTargetPath, MAX_PATH) == 0)
                {
                    return strRawName;
                }
                string strTargetPath = sbTargetPath.ToString();
                if (strFileName.StartsWith(strTargetPath))
                {
                    strFileName = strFileName.Replace(strTargetPath, strDrivePath.Substring(0, 2));
                    break;
                }
            }
            return strFileName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that you're relaying on `oSystemHandleInfo.ObjectType != OBJECT_TYPE_FILE` which will change depending on the Windows version.